# Wait until jQuery.fadeIn() has started but not necessarily finished

Tags: jquery, html, fadein

I'm struggling to work out how to do this. I have some jqGrid elements inside some jQuery UI tabs. To make sure the grids fill the width 100% I've written a simple `window.resize` event.

When the user clicks a button I fade out the tabs, clear and reload the jqGrids, and then fade the tabs back in. You can see it all working here: http://jsfiddle.net/qvY9s/7/ (click the 'Reload' button to see it working).

However, I want the grid to resize to fill the tab as soon as it starts to become visible. If I call `$(window).resize()` immediately after calling `$(..).fadeIn()` on the tabs then it doesn't work - I'm guessing because the animation hasn't started yet and the grid hasn't become visible.

Is there anyway to trigger `window.resize` just after the fade effect has started?

(I don't want to have to wait until the end if I can help it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works well, add this line at the top of loadGrids() function:

`$('#container').show().css('visible', false);`

idea being to make the container invisible but using up its normal layout space before fading it in

jsFiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/qvY9s/9/

Comment: Unfortunately this appears to work, but actually short-circuits the fadeIn effect. You can confirm this by increasing the fadeIn delay - it doesn't have any effect.

Comment: I reworked the order in which things are done in the jsFiddle and you can have a look here.  Basically I set it to visible: false, then do the layout changing updates, then hide, then fade in.  Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/qvY9s/12/

Comment: That works, thanks. However, I don't think `.css('visible', false)` is actually needed (if you remove it from the jsFiddle the effect doesn't change). After investigating, I'm not sure that it's actually valid CSS - `.css('visibility', 'hidden')` is documented, but I can't find any mention of a 'visible' property.

Comment: Ok thanks the reason I do that is to avoid a flash where the #container div becomes visible for a split second then is hidden again, you might see that on slower browsers so might be worth keeping in the form you give.

Answer (score 2):

You could just set a timeout calling directly the resize function:

```
$('#container').fadeIn(2000);
setTimeout(custJqGResize,10);
```

Comment: This makes sense, but is it guaranteed to work every time? I know it's probably a borderline case, but what would happen if the `fadeIn()` effect didn't start until after 10ms? Maybe I'm being pedantic but I'm wary of relying on timers to synchronise effects unless I can be sure they'll always run exactly as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You could just delay an arbitrary amount of time before doing it:

```
setTimeout(function(){$(window).resize()},100);
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qvY9s/8/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the onmousedown and onmouseup event? 
onmousedown -> resize
onmouseup -> fadeIn